# Как рисовать на форме из другого потока? (TThread)

Tags: delphi, winapi, многопоточность, изображения

Имеем поток `TViewSort = class (TThread)`. В нём осуществляем сортировку массива. И очень сильно хотим отображать на форме в `TImage` (или ещё где) изменение массива во  время сортировки из этого потока, то есть что-то рисовать на `TImage`.

Как это реализовать? (Хотелось бы средствами VCL. Если не получится, то можно и WinAPI.)

---

На данный момент имеется `thread`. В него передаётся массив. И на неком временном `bitmap'е`, созданом в Execute потока (`QBitmap:=TBitmap.Create`),  чего-то рисуется через `Canvas`... Но рисуется как-то через раз... И `bitmap` почему-то "сбрасывается" - в некий момент перестаёт обновлятся изображение на нём (проверял через `bitmap.savetofile`). И, например, `bitmap.scanline`[1] возвращает -1. Короче накосячил я чую сильно, поэтому напишу заново.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В демках, которые идет с делфи, есть пример сортировки с отрисовкой на форме. 
А если ближе к делу - у канвы есть методы lock и unlock. Первым блокируете канву, рисуете, что хотите, потом вторым разблокируете.
Помните, что два потока одновременно рисовать не смогут, поэтому слишком долго засиживаться в отрисовке не нужно. Можно ещё [пример](http://www.delphisources.ru/pages/faq/base/threads_example.html) посмотреть.

Если же подготовка изображения сложная, то стоит себе создать битмап в потомке (но не TImage), рисовать там что нужно. А когда придет время обновить на экране - то в три строки обновить - залочили, скопировали, разлочили.

Comment: Большое спасибо! Уже работает по крайней мере...
Ещё такой подвопрос... Рисую я значит на Timage... И иногда на экране не прорисовывается полностью то, что нужно. Как быть?

Comment: TImage не предназначен для рисования. Используйте TPaintBox.

А почему не прорисовывается  - много чего может быть - например, сработала ещё одна прорисовка, которая затирает предыдущую. Вариант два - окно обновилось само по себе, а так как OnPaint/WM_PAINT у Вас скорее всего не перекрыты, поэтому и затерло.

Comment: Оу... Хорошо. Будем использовать TPaintBox. А я что-то слышал, что в нём можно рисовать только по событию onPaint... Сейчас попробуем...